# Using Redcarpet with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, markdown, redcarpet

I installed Redcarpet. I was following 272 Railscast tutorial on how to use it. I have this line in my `show.html.erb`

```
 <%= Redcarpet.new(@topic.text).to_html %>
```

My rails app doesn't seem to know there's Redcarpet. I gives a `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `new' for Redcarpet:Module
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<%= Markdown.new(@topic.text).to_html %>
```

You might want to look at the [definition of that method](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/blob/master/lib/redcarpet/compat.rb#L73).

Comment: Thanks Really helpful.